# Webpack Typescript error Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I'm trying to run Typescript with Webpack, but I seem to run into a problem. Everything works fine untill I introduce typings for variables (e.g. `color:string;` ). Can anyone help me?

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  ...
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            exclude: NODE_DIR, /** path to node_modules folder */
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        }]
    },
    output: output = {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: DIST_DIR /** path to dist folder */
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
    }
}
```

When I try to run my scripts I keep getting this error:

> ERROR in ./src/typescript/class/Car.ts 4:8 Module parse failed:
>   Unexpected token (4:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

index.ts

```
import { Car } from './class/Car ';
let car= new Car ({
    color : 'blue'
});
```

Car.ts

```
export class Car {
    public color:string; /** here is where the error originates */

    constructor(config) { }
}
```

Comment: I believe your `test` of `/\.tsx$/` is not matching the `.ts` extension and should be changed to `/\.tsx?$/`.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Tried that already. Did not fix it...

Comment: what is your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @PlayMa256 In edit. :)